# Redirection ambiguity

Tags: c, linux, gcc, system-calls

I have a file named test.c (Its contents are given below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("T\n");
    fork();
    printf("F\n");
}
```

The expected result is:

```
T
F
F
```

Compiling with gcc and executing `./a.out` ,the output is:

```
T
F
F
```

which matches the expected answer.

**But ambiguity arises when I redirect the output to another file.**

```
$ ./a.out > Output.txt
```

The Output.txt has the following data:

```
T
F
T
F
```

Why is there an additional T in my Output.txt file when I use redirectors?

1) I've check this in multiple PC's running on ubuntu with gcc installed.

2) Tried deleting the Output.txt and moving all the files to a different location, but this still persists.

P.s. this works fine without the redirector.

Comment: The output is buffered. The buffer is duplicated when `fork`ing. It may or not to contain the characters written there before `fork`. If you want a predictable behavior, use `fflush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of the buffer, give a try with the follow code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("T\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
    printf("F\n");
}
```